# How to find a string in a vector in r?

Tags: r

I have created a function that essentially creates a vector of a 1000 binary values. I have been able to count the longest streak of consecutive 1s by using `rle`.

I was wondering how to find a specific vector (say `c(1,0,0,1)`) in this larger vector? I would want it to return the amount of occurrences of that vector. So `c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)` should return 2, while `c(1,0,0,0,1)` should return 0.

Most solutions that I have found just find whether a sequence occurs at all and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, or they give results for the individual values, not the specific vector that is specified.

Here's my code so far:

```
# creates a function where a 1000 people choose either up or down.
updown <- function(){
  n = 1000
  X = rep(0,n)
  Y = rbinom(n, 1, 1 / 2)
  X[Y == 1] = "up"
  X[Y == 0] = "down"

  #calculate the length of the longest streak of ups:
  Y1 <- rle(Y)
  streaks <- Y1$lengths[Y1$values == c(1)]
  max(streaks, na.rm=TRUE)
}

# repeat this process n times to find the average outcome.
longeststring <- replicate(1000, updown())
longeststring(p_vals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Y` is only `0`s and `1`s, we can `paste` it into a string and use regex, specifically `gregexpr`. Simplified a bit:

```
set.seed(47)    # for reproducibility

Y <- rbinom(1000, 1, 1 / 2)

count_pattern <- function(pattern, x){
    sum(gregexpr(paste(pattern, collapse = ''), 
                 paste(x, collapse = ''))[[1]] > 0)
}

count_pattern(c(1, 0, 0, 1), Y)
## [1] 59
```

`paste` reduces the pattern and `Y` down to strings, e.g. `"1001"` for the pattern here, and a 1000-character string for `Y`. `gregexpr` searches for all occurrences of the pattern in `Y` and returns the indices of the matches (together with a little more information so they can be extracted, if one wanted). Because `gregexpr` will return `-1` for no match, testing for numbers greater than 0 will let us simply sum the `TRUE` values to get the number of macthes; in this case, 59.

The other sample cases mentioned:

```
count_pattern(c(1,0,0,1), c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1))
## [1] 2

count_pattern(c(1,0,0,1), c(1,0,0,0,1))
## [1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c(1,0,0,1)
y <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1) 
length(unlist(str_match_all(paste(y, collapse=''), '1001')))
[1] 2
y <- c(1,0,0,0,1)
length(unlist(str_match_all(paste(y, collapse=''), '1001')))
[1] 0
```

If you want to match overlapped patterns,

```
y <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1) # overlapped
length(unlist(gregexpr("(?=1001)",paste(y, collapse=''),perl=TRUE)))
[1] 2
```

Comment: @Feng Tian actually we need to use look-ahead assertions, updated the code, let me know if it does not work.